# NameError: name 'sha1' is not defined

Tags: python, function

Hi when i choose option i alaways get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ran.py", line 26, in 
    sha1()
NameError: name 'sha1' is not defined
But i couldn't know what problem is i tried to put the function before calling but's always the same thing

```
def main():
 print '1 - SHA1  Decrypter'
print '2 - MD5  Decrypter'
select = input("select option :")

if select==1:
  sha1()
elif select==2:
  md5()


def   sha1():
  try:
    sha1 = raw_input("\t\n\nMD5 Hash:")
    dictionary = open("pwds.txt","r")
  except(IOError):
    print "pwds.txt not found!"
for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
    if hashlib.sha1(passwd).hexdigest() == sha1:

        print("\n\t[OK]"+sha1+" : "+passwd+"\n")
        raw_input("Decrytion Success; Press Enter To Exit")

else:
        print "\n\tFailed; Password not found in dictionary"
        main()

def md5():
  try:
    md5 = raw_input("\t\n\nMD5 Hash:")
    dictionary = open("pwds.txt","r")
  except(IOError):
    print "pwds.txt not found!"
for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
    if hashlib.md5(passwd).hexdigest() == md5:

        print("\n\t[OK]"+md5+" : "+passwd+"\n")
        raw_input("Decrytion Success; Press Enter To Exit")

else:
        print "\n\tFailed; Password not found in dictionary"
        main()
main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: You need to have the function defined before you call it.  Additionally, you seem to be using a variable which is also named ```sha1```.  Don't do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in the code

```
import hashlib

def main():
    print '1 - SHA1  Decrypter'
    print '2 - MD5  Decrypter'
    select = input("select option :")

    if select==1:
      sha1()
    elif select==2:
      md5()


def   sha1():
    try:
        sha1 = raw_input("\t\n\nMD5 Hash:")
        dictionary = open("pwds.txt","r")

        for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
            if hashlib.sha1(passwd).hexdigest() == sha1:

                print("\n\t[OK]"+sha1+" : "+passwd+"\n")
                raw_input("Decrytion Success; Press Enter To Exit")

        else:
            print "\n\tFailed; Password not found in dictionary"
            main()
    except(IOError):
        print "pwds.txt not found!"

def md5():
    try:
        md5 = raw_input("\t\n\nMD5 Hash:")
        dictionary = open("pwds.txt","r")
        for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
            if hashlib.md5(passwd).hexdigest() == md5:
                print("\n\t[OK]"+md5+" : "+passwd+"\n")
                raw_input("Decrytion Success; Press Enter To Exit")

        else:
            print "\n\tFailed; Password not found in dictionary"
            main()
    except(IOError):
        print "pwds.txt not found!"
main()
```

1. The indentation in python is important, as it determines the scope of blocks. I don't know if you have the wrong indentation or just made a mistake when posting it.
2. You have to import hashlib
3. You have to declare and use dictionary inside the try block.

Comment: Hashlib is imported also for the indentation it s a mistake when i was posting it